# Value is not getting reflected in <input> when the value is updated from inside of ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular

I have a form-control `myControl` for which I have implemented `ControlValueAccessor` on a component named `ControlComponent`.

In `AppComponent` I have an input which is also bound to `myControl`

**Problem:**

I have a button inside `ControlComponent` which replaces current value with an emoji. The form is getting updated fine when I click that button but the problem is that value is not getting reflected in the `input` in `AppComponent`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-2amjst?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: The same thing happens when using same `formControlName` directive on any two elements. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10036 They are not in sync.

Comment: I am having trouble to understand what you are trying to achieve here, why would you even have the same form control in both your app component and custom?

Comment: I have many inputs in my app. I want all inputs to have one emoji selector which using which user can append an emoji into current value @AJT_82

Comment: Still doesn't really answer why you would display same form control twice? Or am I stupid and not understanding :D

Answer (score -1):

You need to move the `input` tag to the `ControlComponent`.
Add an `@Input` (for example "value") to the `ControlComponent`.
Then you just have to update the `value` in the `writeValue()` function and it works.
The form which is the parent for the component is also correctly updated.

Template

```
<input [value]="value">
<button (click)="change('')">
  set value: 
</button>
```

ControlComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-control',
  templateUrl: './control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./control.component.css'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => ControlComponent),
    multi: true,
  }]
})
export class ControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() value: string;
  onChange: (val: string) => void;
  onTouched: () => void;

  constructor() { }

  touch() {
    this.onTouched();
  }

  change(val: string) {
    this.onChange(val);
    this.value = val;
  }

  writeValue(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
    console.log(`write value ${value}`);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChange = fn;
    console.log('onChange')
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
    console.log('onTouched')
  }

  setDisabledState() { }
}
```

AppComponent

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <app-control formControlName="myControl"></app-control>
</form>

<div>
    <span>Value: {{myForm.get('myControl').value}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry  but that doesn't answer anything. Its a minimal reproduction of the problem and not my actual use case.

Comment: @dasfdsa can you describe the problem with more details? And explain why do you need the custom form control?

Comment: I have many inputs in my app. I want all inputs to have one emoji selector which using which user can append an emoji into current value

Comment: @dasfdsa I updated the answer according to you comment. Hope I understand it correctly this time

Comment: Yes you understood right but `this.value = value;`. You can try it in my stackblitz.

Comment: @dasfdsa again I don't understand what you want to say by that. What is the problem with `this.value = value;`?